# Can I optimize my database by splitting one big table into many small ones?

Tags: mysql, optimization, split

Assume that I have one big table with three columns: "user_name", "user_property", "value_of_property". Lat's also assume that I have a lot of user (let say 100 000) and a lot of properties (let say 10 000). Then the table is going to be huge (1 billion rows).

When I extract information from the table I always need information about a particular user. So, I use, for example `where user_name='Albert Gates'`. So, every time the mysql server needs to analyze 1 billion lines to find those of them which contain "Albert Gates" as user_name.

Would it not be wise to split the big table into many small ones corresponding to fixed users?

Comment: what you are describing is called partitioning. In databases you design you rtable structure around your data. You set the hardware up to manage this kind of problem. I believe parttioning (which is the sql server lingo for what you are talking about) is a feature that is not in mysql - or it wasn't 7 years ago when i switched to sql server - which i know does support it.

Comment: @John Nicholas: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: coool tyvm ;)mysql does have partitioning afterall

Comment: The question you ask and the problem you present are two different things. Partitioning makes sense in some cases, but the problem illustrated in the body is an EAV design, which is something completely separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think that is a good idea. A better approach is to [add an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the `user_name` column - and perhaps another index on `(user_name, user_property)` for looking up a single property. Then the database does not need to scan all the rows - it just need to find the appropriate entry in the index which is stored in a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), making it easy to find a record in a very small amount of time.

If your application is still slow even after correctly indexing it can sometimes be a good idea to [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) your largest tables.

One other thing you could consider is normalizing your database so that the user_name is stored in a separate table and use an integer foriegn key in its place. This can reduce storage requirements and can increase performance. The same may apply to `user_property`.

Comment: the other advantage of normalising out user_name and using its id in other tables is that if you need to change it you don't have to update potentially thousands of records and all their relations.

Answer (score 3):

you should **normalise** your design as follows:

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
username varbinary(32) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists properties;
create table properties
(
property_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop table if exists user_property_values;
create table user_property_values
(
user_id int unsigned not null,
property_id smallint unsigned not null,
value varchar(255) not null,
primary key (user_id, property_id),
key (property_id)
)
engine=innodb;

insert into users (username) values ('f00'),('bar'),('alpha'),('beta');

insert into properties (name) values ('age'),('gender');

insert into user_property_values values 
(1,1,'30'),(1,2,'Male'),
(2,1,'24'),(2,2,'Female'),
(3,1,'18'),
(4,1,'26'),(4,2,'Male');
```

From a performance perspective the innodb clustered index works wonders in this similar example (COLD run):

```
select count(*) from product
count(*)
========
1,000,000 (1M)

select count(*) from category
count(*)
========
250,000 (500K)

select count(*) from product_category
count(*)
========
125,431,192 (125M)

select
 c.*,
 p.*
from
 product_category pc
inner join category c on pc.cat_id = c.cat_id
inner join product p on pc.prod_id = p.prod_id
where
 pc.cat_id = 1001;
0:00:00.030: Query OK (0.03 secs)
```

Comment: please comment if you down vote otherwise you're just demonstrating your ignorance.

Comment: I don;t think you have normalised anything. What has been normlaised? What order of normalisation is it? What repetition of data has been eliminated? Also (and this is nit picky, i'm sorry) where are you going to store the value of the property? Do you really want the properties to hav ea many to many relationship? Currently each property can be shared between multiple users and it will be very hard to have required properties.

Comment: sorry I deleted it whilst I reflected.

Comment: agreed EAV relational models suck - +1 for stating the obvious :P

Answer (score 2):

Properly indexing your database will be the number 1 way of improving performance.  I once had a query take a half an hour (on a large dataset, but none the less).  Then we come to find out that the tables had no index.  Once indexed the query took less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have this table structure. My fundemental problem is that you are going to have to cast the data in value of property every time you want to use it. That is bad in my opinion - also storing numbers as text is crazy given that its all binary anyway. For instance how are you going to have required fields? Or fields that need to have constraints based on other fields? Eg start and end date?

Why not simply have the properties as fields rather than some many to many relationship?

have 1 flat table. When your business rules begin to show that properties should be grouped then you can consider moving them out into other tables and have several 1:0-1 relationships with the users table. But this is not normalization and it will degrade performance slightly due to the extra join (however the self documenting nature of the table names will greatly aid any developers)

One way i regularly see databqase performance get totally castrated is by having a generic

Id, property Type, Property Name, Property Value table.

This is really lazy but exceptionally flexible but totally kills performance. In fact on a new job where performance is bad i actually ask if they have a table with this structure - it invariably becomes the center point of the database and is slow. The whole point of relational database design is that the relations are determined ahead of time. This is simply a technique that aims to speed up development at a huge cost to application speed. It also puts a huge reliance on business logic in the application layer to behave - which is not defensive at all. Eventually you find that you wan to use properties in a key relationsip which leads to all kinds of casting on the join which further degrades performance.

If data has a 1:1 relationship with an entity then it should be a field on the same table. If your table gets to more than 30 fields wide then consider movign them into another table *but dont call it normalisation because it isnt*. It is a technique to help developers group fields together at the cost of performance in an attempt to aid understanding.

I don't know if mysql has an equivalent but sqlserver 2008 has sparse columns - null values take no space.
[SParse column datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx)

I'm not saying a EAV approach is always wrong, but i think using a relational database for this approach is probably not the best choice.